# Find the unique solution to the IVP $x' = Ax$ where $A = \begin{bmatrix} {-3}&{2} \\ {-1}&{-1}\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, initial-value-problems

I began this problem by evaulating $x' = Ax$. Let $$ x' = \begin{bmatrix}{x_1} \\ {x_2}\end{bmatrix}.$$ Then we have
$$x'_1=-3x_1 + 2x_2, $$
$$x'_2=-x_1 - x_2, $$
$$x_1(0)=1,$$
$$x_2(0)=-2.$$
From the first equation we have $x_2= \frac{1}{2}x'_1+ \frac{3}{2}x_1$. Substituting this into the second equation yields:
$$x''_1+4x'_1-2x_1=0,$$
The characteristic equation of this is $m^2+4m-2=0$, which has the solutions $m = -2 \pm \sqrt{6}$.

However, I am confused how to proceed to finding the final solution. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to now find the eigenvectors corresponding to these eigenvalues, which will help you diagonalize the matrix $A$. Once you do that , and write say $A = P^{-1}DP$ then we know that the solution is $x(t) = P^{-1}e^{tD}P$, where $e^{tD}$ is easy to find for a diagonal matrix. The basic idea behind all this is that $x(t) = e^{At}$ is known to be the unique solution, but $e^{At}$ can be calculated precisely only by diagonalizing $A$ (more precisely, finding its Jordan Canonical form, but in this simple case diagonalizability is sufficient).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}x' &= -3x + 2 y \\ y' &= - x- y \end{align}$$

Taking the derivative of the first equation and substituting to isolate $x$

$$x'' = -3 x' + 2 y' = -3 x'+2(-x-y) = -3x' + 2(-x -\dfrac{1}{2}(x' + 3 x)) = - 4 x' - 5x$$

We now have

$$x'' + 4 x' + 5 x = 0, x(0) = 1, x'(0) = -7$$

This leads to

$$x(t) = e^{-2t}(\cos(t) - 5 \sin(t))$$

From the first equation, we know

$$y(t) = \dfrac{1}{2}(x' + 3 x) = -e^{-2 t} (3 \sin (t)+2 \cos (t))$$

We can also solve this using eigenvalues and eigenvectors and many other methods (undetermined coefficients, Laplace transforms, matrix exponential, diagonalization...).